# How to prove that $\log(d) , d \sim U(a,b)$ is exponentially distributed (PDF)?

Tags: probability

I read that logarithm of a standard uniform distribution is exponential PDF. Is it possible to prove that $\log(D)$ with uniform distribution between $(a,b)$ is also a exponential (has exponential PDF)?
In fact, my variable is a distance between distance a and distance b, and I am computing $\log10(D)$ in equal spaces in distance.
Thanks for any help.
Regards.

Comment: A particular case : https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/234544/147896

Answer (score 1):

$X \sim U(a,b)$

Let $Y=\log X $

$F_{Y}(y)=P(Y \le y)=P(\log X \le y)=P(\log X \le y)=P( X \le e^{y})=F_X({e^{y})}$

$\dfrac{d(F_{Y})}{dy}=f_{X}(e^y)e^y=\dfrac{e^y}{b-a}\   \ \bigg( y \in(\log a,\;\log b\bigg)$

Not exponential distribution you can see that.

Comment: Thank for answer. I think if we Let Y = -logX , then the answer becomes like exponential.

Comment: Also this should hold that $X \sim U(0,1)$

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to transform cumulative distributions. So, what's the cumulative distiribution of $\log D$? Say $x$ is between $\log a$ and $\log b$. Then
$$
P(\log D\leq x) = P(D\leq 10^x) = \frac{10^x - a}{b-a}
$$
For any other $x$, it's either $0$ or $1$.

To get the PDF, you can just differentiate this to get
$$
f_{\log D}(x) = \cases{\displaystyle \frac{\ln 10}{b-a}\cdot 10^x & if $\log a< x <\log b$\\0 & otherwise}
$$

Comment: I am not sure that the OP intended by using "log" that it"s "decimal logarithm".

Comment: @JeanMarie They did write "$\log10(D)$" in there, and with nothing else to go on, that's what I'm going for.

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice.